# How to deepcopy with multiple references onto same object becoming independent

Tags: python, deep-copy

When using copy.deepcopy on a Python list which has e.g. three references to the same object (i.e. same id), the new list will be referencing deep copies of this object, i.e. a different id - but still those three will be the same id. Is it possible to somehow make them three different ids? Meaning that the new list would be referencing three different objects in terms of id (albeit content wise they would still be the same).

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of each list from the original list.

Using list comprehension:

```
a_list=[1,2,3]
list_1=[a_list,a_list,a_list]
list_2=[i.copy() for i in list_1]
```

Using a for loop:

```
a_list=[1,2,3]
list_1=[a_list,a_list,a_list]
list_2=[]
for i in list_1:
    list_2.append(i.copy())
```